# Testng java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: null, nullpointerexception, testng

I followed the instructions on http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2009/10/dataprovider-data-driven-testing-with.html?showComment=1321643221128 to create my script. The example code worked perfectly. I did not make any major changes except for in the @test section. For some reason i get the error  java.lang.NullPointerException. I am unable to figure out what could be causing this.

```
package script;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.io.File;
import jxl.*; 


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Testcase1 extends SeleneseTestCase{

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //SeleniumServer seleniumserver=new SeleniumServer();
        //seleniumserver.boot();
        //seleniumserver.start();
        setUp("http://devblade08-08:8080", "*firefox");
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.windowFocus();
    }


    @DataProvider(name = "Data")
    public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception{
        Object[][] retObjArr=getTableArray("test\\Resources\\Data\\TestCase1.xls",
                "Scenario", "TestCase1");
        return(retObjArr);
    }

    @Test (dataProvider = "Data")
    public void testTestcase1(String Username, String Password, String Performance) throws Exception {    



        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("link=Â» AudienceView Online");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("name=BOset::WScontent::SearchCriteria::search_criteria", "Star Trek Automation");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"submit\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("//div[@id='search_results']/form/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[5]/a/span");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("css=div.seattab_off");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=BOparam::WSorder::getBestAvailable::reqNum::EA25EE97-EA9B-41B2-8D03-BC6B647F1255::select");
        selenium.select("id=BOparam::WSorder::getBestAvailable::reqNum::EA25EE97-EA9B-41B2-8D03-BC6B647F1255::select", "label=2");
        selenium.click("css=option[value=\"2\"]");
        selenium.click("name=doWork::WSorder::getBestAvailable");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=popupDiv_okayButton");
        selenium.click("name=continue");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("name=loginName");
        selenium.type("name=loginName", "banana");
        selenium.type("name=loginPassword", "banana");
        selenium.click("name=login");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");






    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        selenium.close();
        selenium.stop();
    } 

    public String[][] getTableArray(String xlFilePath, String sheetName, String tableName) throws Exception{
        String[][] tabArray=null;

            Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlFilePath));
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName); 
            int startRow,startCol, endRow, endCol,ci,cj;
            Cell tableStart=sheet.findCell(tableName);
            startRow=tableStart.getRow();
            startCol=tableStart.getColumn();

            Cell tableEnd= sheet.findCell(tableName, startCol+1,startRow+1, 100, 64000,  false);                

            endRow=tableEnd.getRow();
            endCol=tableEnd.getColumn();
            System.out.println("startRow="+startRow+", endRow="+endRow+", " +
                    "startCol="+startCol+", endCol="+endCol);
            tabArray=new String[endRow-startRow-1][endCol-startCol-1];
            ci=0;

            for (int i=startRow+1;i<endRow;i++,ci++){
                cj=0;
                for (int j=startCol+1;j<endCol;j++,cj++){
                    tabArray[ci][cj]=sheet.getCell(j,i).getContents();
                }
            }


        return(tabArray);
    }


}//end of class
```

Answer (score 2):

Without access to the system under test it is difficult to see where the problem is.
I did think the following line is either wrong or deserving of a comment about the reversed indexing:

```
tabArray[ci][cj]=sheet.getCell(j,i).getContents()
```

If the indicies to getCell() are improperly reversed this could cause the attempt to call getContents() to throw an NPE.

I certainly think you should have used a debugger or included material in your question about why you couldn't provide a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Include a stack trace, or better: study the stack trace. It will tell you exactly where the problem is (and it's more likely to be in your code than TestNG, IMO).